# Facebook login page doesn't show my score only happens for admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

after I log onto Facebook and everything, it works fine but when I try to show my friend's score it doesn't brings up the score the score would be zero all the time, except for the admin account which is mine, it shows up my actual score, and here are the scripts for the Facebook and also for the score manager of mine, any suggestions?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int score;

    Text scoretext;

    void Start () 
    {
        scoretext = GetComponent<Text> () ;
        //score = 0;

        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CurrentPlayerScore");
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if (score <0)
            score = 0;
        scoretext.text = "" + score;
    }

    public static void AddPoints (int pointsToAdd)
    {
        score +=pointsToAdd;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CurrentPlayerScore", score);
    }

    public static void Rest()
    {
        score = 0;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CurrentPlayerScore", score);
    }
}
```

and this is Facebook's one

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class FBholder : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject UIFBIsLoggedIn;
    public GameObject UIFBIsNotLoggedIn;
    public GameObject UIFBAvatar;
    public GameObject UIFUserName;

    private List<object> scoresList = null;

    public GameObject ScoreEntryPanel;
    public GameObject ScoreScrollList;

    public static int score;

    private Dictionary<string, string> profile = null;

    void Awake()
    {
        FB.Init (SetInit, OnHideUnity);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CurrentPlayerScore");
    }


    private void SetInit()
    {
        Debug.Log ("FB Init done.");

        if(FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            DealWithFBMenus(true);
            Debug.Log ("FB Logged In");
        }
        else
        {
            DealWithFBMenus(false);
        }

    }

    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {

        if(!isGameShown)
        {
            Time.timeScale =0;
        }
        else
        {
            Time.timeScale =1;
        }


    }

    public void FBlogin()
    {
        FB.Login ("email,publish_actions", AuthCallback);
    }

    void AuthCallback (FBResult result)
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            Debug.Log ("FB Login worked!");
            DealWithFBMenus(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log ("Fb Login fail");
            DealWithFBMenus(false);
        }
    }

    void DealWithFBMenus (bool isLoggedIn)
    {
        if(isLoggedIn)
        {
            UIFBIsLoggedIn.SetActive(true);
            UIFBIsNotLoggedIn.SetActive(false);

            FB.API (Util.GetPictureURL("me", 128, 128), Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, DealWithProfilePicture);
            FB.API ("/me?field=id,first_name",Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, DealWiththeUserName);
        }
        else
        {
            UIFBIsLoggedIn.SetActive(false);
            UIFBIsNotLoggedIn.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    void DealWithProfilePicture(FBResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Problem with getting profile picture");

            FB.API (Util.GetPictureURL("me", 128, 128), Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, DealWithProfilePicture);
            return;
        }

        Image UserAvatar = UIFBAvatar.GetComponent<Image>();
        UserAvatar.sprite = Sprite.Create (result.Texture, new Rect (0,0,128, 128), new Vector2 (0,0));
    }

    void DealWiththeUserName (FBResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Problem with getting user name");

            FB.API ("/me?field=id,first_name",Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, DealWiththeUserName);
            return;
        }

        profile = Util.DeserializeJSONProfile(result.Text);

        Text UserMsg = UIFUserName.GetComponent<Text>();

        UserMsg.text = "Hello, " + profile["first_name"];
    }

    public void ShareWithFriends()
    {
        FB.Feed (
            linkCaption: "I'm Playing this awesome game check it out!",
            picture: "http://stormyx.com/MyGameIcon.png",
            linkName: "Come join me in this game now!",
            link: "http://app.facebook.com/" + FB.AppId + "/?challenge_brag=" + (FB.IsLoggedIn ? FB.UserId : "guest")


            );
    }

    public void InviteFriends()
    {
        FB.AppRequest
            (
                message: "This game is Fantastic!, join me now!",
                title: "Invite your friends to join you"
                );
    }

    public void FriendsScore()
    {
        FB.API ("/app/scores?fields=score,user.limit(30)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,ScoresCallback);
    }

    private void ScoresCallback (FBResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Scores callback: " + result.Text);

        scoresList = Util.DeserializeScores (result.Text);

        foreach(Transform child in ScoreScrollList.transform)
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }

        foreach(object score in scoresList)
        {
            var entry = (Dictionary<string,object>) score;
            var user = (Dictionary<string,object>) entry ["user"];


            GameObject ScorePanel;
            ScorePanel = Instantiate (ScoreEntryPanel) as GameObject;
            ScorePanel.transform.parent = ScoreScrollList.transform;

            Transform ThisScoreName = ScorePanel.transform.Find ("FriendName");
            Transform ThisScoreScore = ScorePanel.transform.Find ("FriendScore");
            Text ScoreName = ThisScoreName.GetComponent<Text>();
            Text ScoreScore = ThisScoreScore.GetComponent<Text>();


            ScoreName.text = user["name"].ToString();
            ScoreScore.text = entry["score"].ToString();

            ScoreName.text = user["name"].ToString();
            ScoreScore.text = entry["score"].ToString();

            Transform TheUserAvatar = ScorePanel.transform.Find ("FriendAvatar");
            Image UserAvatar = TheUserAvatar.GetComponent<Image>();

            FB.API (Util.GetPictureURL(user["id"].ToString(), 128,128), Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,delegate(FBResult pictureResult) 
                    {
                if(pictureResult.Error != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log (pictureResult.Error);
                } 
                else
                {
                    UserAvatar.sprite = Sprite.Create (pictureResult.Texture, new Rect (0,0,128, 128), new Vector2 (0,0));
                }
            });


        }
    }

    public void MyScore()
    { 
        var scoreData = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        scoreData ["score"] = (score).ToString();
        FB.API ("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, delegate(FBResult result)
                {
            Debug.Log ("Score submit result: " + result.Text);
        }, scoreData);
    }

    public void StartGame ()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CurrentPlayerScore",0);
        Application.LoadLevel (1);
    }

    public void Quit ()
    {
        Application.Quit ();
    }



}
```

Comment: Are you testing this with an app which is public or in development mode?

Comment: No sir, it's a game I already create and did publish it and now it's not working when I show scores it shows mine, but anyone else it doesn't it shows score is zero, why is that?